# WinForms ListView selection changes randomly when assigning selected index from code

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm running into very strange WinForms behavior that seems to be a framework bug.

Situation:

On an empty form, put 2 `ListView`s next to each other. Disable `HideSelection` to make the selection visible while the control does not have focus. The `View` property (details, large icon) does not seem to matter, but I find details makes it easier to click (in which case, add one column).

It also does not matter whether or not `MultiSelect` is enabled or not.

[image]

(button1 is not involved)

In the form constructor, put some items into the lists:

```
this.listView1.Items.Add("item1-1");
this.listView1.Items.Add("item1-2");
this.listView1.Items.Add("item1-3");

this.listView2.Items.Add("item2-1");
this.listView2.Items.Add("item2-2");
```

Now, when the user selects something in `listView1`, we want the item with the same list index to become selected in `listView2`. E.g. user selects `item1-1` in the left list view, we want to select `item2-1` in the right list view and so on.

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // (*1)
    this.listView2.SelectedIndices.Clear();

    if (this.listView1.SelectedIndices.Count != 0 && this.listView1.SelectedIndices[0] < this.listView2.Items.Count)
    {
        // (*1) can also be put here; it makes no difference with regards to the bug (it makes a functional difference though)
        this.listView2.SelectedIndices.Add(this.listView1.SelectedIndices[0]);
    }
}
```

The bug sometimes occurs in the following scenario (I can only reproduce if I carry these steps out very quickly (as in, less than a second overall)):

- Click item 1 (starting to count at 1) in left list
- Item 1 in right list becomes selected automatically
- Click item 1 in right list
- Click item 2 in left list
- Item 2 in right list becomes selected automatically
- Click item 2 in right list
- Click item 1 in left list
- Item 1 in right list becomes selected automatically
- Wait a while (ca. 300 ms)
- Item 2 in right list becomes selected automatically (Incorrect!)

More generally (this is my conjecture):

- Click an item in the left list
- Click the item in the right list *which just got automatically selected*
- *Quickly* select a *different* item in the left list
- The correct item is automatically selected in the right list for a brief moment
- The selection jumps back to the previous item after a short delay

I can also observe the invalid selection change in the right list with this event handler, but I can't get any use out of the breakpoint - there doesn't seem to be anything suspicious to me. In the faulty case, the call stack only contains framework internal methods (except for the topmost frame, which is the event handler, of course), so the bogus selection change comes from the framework itself.

```
private void listView2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.listView1.SelectedIndices.Count == 0 || this.listView2.SelectedIndices.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (this.listView2.SelectedIndices[0] != this.listView1.SelectedIndices[0])
    {
        // Unless the user MANUALLY selects a DIFFERENT item in the right list view, this should never happen, but it does!
        int j = 5; // BREAKPOINT HERE
    }
}
```

The bug does not always happen and seems to be rather timing sensitive, but after some "practice" I can reproduce it about 50 % of the time now.

My guess is that there's some really dumb failsafe mechanism in there. When the user clicks on an item, WinForms just decides to check a short while later if that item really got selected, and if it's not selected, it selects it again (even though the selection was changed programmatically in the meantime). But that alone can't be it, because the bug does not occur unless you explicitly click on the automatically selected item right after the selection changed automatically.

Can anyone reproduce this, and how could I work around this?

This happens to me on Win 10 x64, with .NET frameworks 4.5.2 and 4.7

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with Winforms, ListView is provided by the OS and has been subjected to 20 years of appcompat hacks.  That selection is wonky is something you already discovered by having to test for SelectedIndices.Count == 0.  You likewise want to avoid SelectedIndices.Clear().

Comment: @HansPassant It sounds a bit like you're suggesting that I should avoid using a `ListView` to begin with (or at least avoid selecting things programmatically) and design the GUI differently. Which is, in fact, currently what I'm trying to do. But I find this issue very strange nonetheless because unless it has something to do with my machine in particular, it means that everyone selecting items from code may run into this issue sooner or later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you have to set the "focused item" as well, either via `ListViewItem.Focused` or `ListView.FocusedItem`, e.g.:

```
this.listView2.SelectedIndices.Clear();

if (this.listView1.SelectedIndices.Count != 0 && this.listView1.SelectedIndices[0] < this.listView2.Items.Count)
{
   var item_we_want_to_select = this.listView2.Items[this.listView1.SelectedIndices[0]];
   item_we_want_to_select.Selected = true;
   item_we_want_to_select.Focused = true;
}
```

However all this sounds fishy and I would not use a ListView for such a GUI again. I cannot comfortably tell (nor quote the documentation) about what any of that *exactly* does, whether it is the correct approach, and whether it has any unintended side effects. It stills seems to me as if the original observation is a Windows bug and this is a workaround that may or may not work.